# How i insert data from one server database to another server database using MySQL?

Tags: mysql

MY task is to send data from a database table from my server to another database table on another server.The problem is i just want to use MySQL query.
I don't want to use any scripting language

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: `insert into database_name.table_name ...`

Comment: First i write this code : INSERT INTO dstDatabase. dstTable SELECT * FROM srsDatabase .srcTable WHERE id>(SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id),0) FROM dstDatabase. dstTable);

Comment: But now i want this process to do on different servers

Comment: Is their any one to help to solve my question ?? thanks